# Replace bean at runtime

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

The codebase is typical spring based enterprise codebase with about 1.5m lines of code. We have quite a few spring context files. The test infra is a problem.

For the test cases, I created another set of test-spring files (mostly it imports relevant project spring contexts) and for few beans contains mocked beans for external services. All Test classes use the same set of context configuration files and things are well 90% of the times.

But in some cases, there would be a bean which I would like to mock. But I do not wish to edit the spring-text.xml (as it will disturb all classes), nor do I wish to have separate set of xml's for each test class. One very simple say of doing it would be:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("fundManager")
FundManager fundManager;

@Test
public void testSomething(){
    TransactionManager tx = mock(TransactionManager.class);
    fundManager.setTransactionManager(tx);
    //now all is well.
}
```

This works in some cases. But sometimes, it is desired that this new temporary bean `tx` should be set where ever `TransactionManager` bean was being used all across the code base.

Proxy class IMHO is not a great solution, because I would then have to wrap all the beans with a wrapper. This is what I am ideally looking for:

```
@Test
public void testSomething(){
    TransactionManager tx = mock(TransactionManager.class);
    replace("transactionManagerBean",tx);
    //For bean with id:transactionManagerBean should be replace with `tx`
}
```

`BeanPostProcessor` looks like an alternate suggestion but I have faced a few hiccups with it.

Comment: Why aren't you just creating a test configuration which overrides/replaces the beans you need? That basically works out-of-the-box without any hacking. In your test case create a `public static class` annotate with `@Configuration`, assuming you use XML add `@ImportResource` to load the configuration. Now define `@Bean` methods for the beans you want to override `@Bean public TransactionManager transactionManager() { return mock(TransactionManager.class);}`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks. Yes, that works but that would also mean I would have different set of config classes for each Test-class file hence creating class pollution.

Comment: Why would that be pollution trying to replace beans is even worse imho...

Comment: Secondly, in your solution, putting `@Bean public TransactionManager transactionManager() { return mock(TransactionManager.class);}` does not seem to override the bean with id `transactionManager` in xml. It still refers to the bean provided in xml.

Comment: That depends on how you are loading your configuration. You have to put an empty `@ContextConfiguration` on your test class else your configuration won't be used

Comment: Also if you are using a lot of mocks and custom configuration this might be a sign that you are testing the wrong thing. Maybe you should be testing a single class and not a fully constructed application context (which would make it an integration test and not a unit test!).

Comment: If it is empty, how will it then take my other beans? For clarity purpose: http://pastebin.com/WNsijY0p

Comment: Have you actually read my initial comment? Add a `public static class TestConfig` to your test and annotate that class with `@Configuration`. The test support will automatically detect this configuration class.

Comment: Aha. Now I get it. I wouldn't go that way simply for the sake of having a separate class for each custom configuration. If I can replace bean via some mechanism and let infra do the dirty work, it is far less classes and code

Comment: Thanks again for the time :)

Comment: When you say "Proxy class", do you also mean `Providers` ? You could create a generic `Provider` class with a setter and doing all the plumbing. The downside is that you will have to replace all accesses by `beanProvider.get()....`

Answer (score 8):

Imagine you have bean A injected into bean B:

```
public static class A {
}

public static class B {
    @Autowired
    private A a;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "B [a=" + a + ']';
    }
}
```

And spring context to initialize your application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean id="a" class="test.Test$A"/>
    <bean id="b" class="test.Test$B"/>
</beans>
```

Then the following snippet will replace all beans A across the context:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("test.xml");

    System.out.println(ctx.getBean("b"));

    final A replacement = new A();
    for (String name : ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
        final Object bean = ctx.getBean(name);
        ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(bean.getClass(),
            field -> {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                field.set(bean, replacement);
            },
            // Here you can provide your filtering.
            field -> field.getType().equals(A.class)
        );
    }

    System.out.println(ctx.getBean("b"));
}
```

This example was made with Java 8 + Spring 4.1. However it would be simple to modify the code for the elder versions of both Java and Spring.