# Getting bean descriptions from a spring application context xml without initializing the beans?

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

Is there a decent way to read a spring application context from xml without initializing the beans right away, so they can be mocked or not, before they are actually created?

Yes, I know about lazy-init, but the actual applicationContext.xml is taboo for me.

The situation is that I have to create some JUnit tests on an application which has been created in a way that puts some difficulties in the way:

1. the configuration file must not be altered, nor the code that is to be tested
2. there are a lot of beans, some of them rather complex and hard to mock
3. part of the test is to use as many of the beans un-mocked as possible
4. some of the beans implement `InitializingBean`, verifying the environment on initialization and throw errors when Jenkins tries to build.

`new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("config.xml")` immediately initializes the beans and throws errors if not in an appropriate environment.

What I have tried:

I have tried Powermock whenNew to mock the offending beans but to do that I would have to know the class which actually creates the beans.  As this class belongs to the spring framework, it may change with future versions. When using @PrepareEverythingForTest it results in an StackOverflow exception. The application is real life, not a small piece of code from some tutorial.

I also searched for something like *ForceLazy*FileSystemXmlApplicationContext but didn't find anything.

Pleas don't start nagging about bad design, I know about that.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please ask one question for each item you want to address and provide examples when possible. About #1 I recommend using `@ContextConfiguration` so you can specify your own configuration for each test without changing the original configuration.

Comment: @Rafa thanks for '@'ContextConfiguration, but part of the point is to test the original configuration, minus the offending beans. So as of the question, I would like to know a way to pre-fetch the bean descriptions and mock some of them. I really don't know how to split this into different questions.

Comment: my line of thought is: 1. Copy your original configuration to a testing 
 configuration file; 2. Change the beans you want to mock in the testing configuration file. Hence, you will end up with the original beans plus the mocked beans only when required.

Comment: @Rafa but if the original config changes that will be double trouble for the copied beans wont change with the original file.

Comment: Gyro, yes. The application-context.xml is an intrinsic part of the application, changes to it are to be considered changes in the application itself. This is not an ideal scenario and sadly is a result of the bad design you are dealing with. The other alternative is to do what @A.Alexander suggested. Be prepared for some heavy lifting. Good luck.

Comment: @Rafa "This is not an ideal scenario and sadly ..." right you are! At least it is somehow comforting to know that I'm not missing any obvious and cheap solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own applicationContext for your testing purpose. There you need to write your own BeanFactory. In that factory you can replace some of beans with mocks.

Comment: I haven't thought of that, because one point of the test is to test as many beans, including their configuration. So, how would I read in the original applicationContext.xml ?

Comment: Let spring load the `applicationContext.xml` and change the `ApplicationContext` in your tests. Something around those lines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33016704/replace-bean-at-runtime

Answer (score 0):

I just remembered about an option. Evaluate if you can use *spring profiles*. It will allow to choose a different implementation based on profiles.

Example:

```
<!-- This is the default myBean -->
<beans>
    <bean id="myBean" class="mypackage.MyBean" />
</beans>
<!-- This is the mocked myBean for testing purposes, it will take place when testingProfile is active -->
<beans profile="testingProfile">
    <bean id="myBean" class="mypackage.MyBeanMock" />
</beans>
```

You can indicate which profile to use via properties or environment variables. Example, if you are using maven in your project you could run the tests as:

```
mvn test -Dspring.profiles.active="testingProfile"
```

Take a look at:

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles

https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/